# Clearing ColorConvertedBitmap in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, reset

the problem is: I want to use the same ColorConvertedBitmap object for two purposes, firstly I set everyting:

```
ColorConvertedBitmap conv = new ColorConvertedBitmap();
conv.BeginInit();
conv.SourceColorContext = new ColorContext(PixelFormats.Bgra32);
conv.Source = myImage;
conv.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Pbgra32;
conv.DestinationColorContext = new ColorContext(PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
conv.EndInit();
```

and then I would like to use the same object for another transformation. How to reset the values of ColorConvertedBitmap?

Thank you for the reply!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've never used that class, but just looking at the members, it seems like setting the Source property would let you reuse it